# How to concatenate string from XML in EditText

Tags: android-xml

I need to add a sort of salt to a password field in Android. The problem is its with firebaseUI and i do not have direct access to the password EditText. but i do have access to it through styles.

For example in [firebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) for android we can do the following:

textPassword

that overrides the styles in the password field. I'd like to be able to add a string that would be concatenated to every password here. so essentially i want to do this in xml.  if the users entered password is "1234" and my salt is "mysecret_salt" then the final password sent to firebase should be: "mysecret_salt1234".  is there anyway to do this through xml since i dont have access to the password EditText directly ?

[source:](http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/salt)

> In password protection, salt is a random string of data used to modify a password hash. Salt can be added to the hash to prevent a collision by uniquely identifying a user's password, even if another user in the system has selected the same password. Salt can also be added to make it more difficult for an attacker to break into a system by using password hash-matching strategies because adding salt to a password hash prevents an attacker from testing known dictionary words across the entire system.

if there is now way to add to the password from client side, is there a way to do it in firebase console ?